# Plotting .cif (Crystallographic Information Framework) files in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

This is more of a wondering question than a problemcentric one.

I was wondering if there was a good way of plotting `.cif` files in LaTeX.

The Crystallographic Information Framework (CIF) is a fileformat for storing crystallographic information, it stores the crystal unit cell vectors, and the fractional coordinates of each atom within the unit cell, along with each atom type.

When plotted in figures there are certain standard color schemes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPK_coloring), such as oxygen being red and carbon black.

Currently if I had to make a picture of a crystal structure I would properly open it in Vesta and create a picture there, or read it in python, and create a picture there.

It would, however, be nice with more TeX friendly approach to showing crystal structures and the like in LaTeX. So Does a good interface for this exist?

Something like

```
\importcif{coolstructure.cif}{ang1}{ang2}{distance}{xrepeat}{yrepeat}{zrepeat}
```

where the command knows all the standard colors and sizes of the atoms?

Comment: Might be more helpful to others here if you start by explaining what cif files are. Others might never have heard about them before.

Comment: ... and it might also help if you explained what you mean by "standard colors".

Comment: @daleif  I've tried to explain these now, I was more curios if something like this already existed, or if I should just continue exporting pictures from other places.

Comment: This would be challenging: there is all of the spacegroup stuff to do. That said, ORTEP was written in the 1960s so the overall memory requirements, _etc._, are likely accessible on a modern system. I guess no-one has done it ...  The other issue is I suspect that getting a good view of a molecule is very much a visual task.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72458/discussion-on-question-by-thorbjorn-e-k-christensen-plotting-cif-files-in-l).

Comment: Are you looking to a plot a single unit cell? An arbitrary number of unit cells? An arbitrary chunk of crystal?